# $a^2+b^2+c^2 \geq a(\frac{c^3+b^3}{2})^{\frac{1}{3}}+b(\frac{a^3+c^3}{2})^{\frac{1}{3}}+ c(\frac{a^3+b^3}{2})^{\frac{1}{3}}$

Tags: inequality

Let $a,b,c>0$. Prove that:
$$a^2+b^2+c^2 \geq a\left(\frac{c^3+b^3}{2}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}+b\left(\frac{a^3+c^3}{2}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}+ c\left(\frac{a^3+b^3}{2}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}$$
I tried with Mildorf lemma: $$\frac{a^2+b^2}{a+b}\geq\sqrt[3]{\frac{a^3+b^3}{2}}.$$
So we need to prove: $$a^2+b^2+c^2 \geq \sum_{cyc} \frac{c(a^2+b^2)}{a+b}$$

But I got stuck here, hope some body helps me please!! Thanks you for all your helps and hints!

Comment: On AoPS: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1844615p12412191

Comment: Yes, I took it from there, and I want a solution using the lemma

Answer (score 2):

$$a^2+b^2+c^2\ge\sum_{cyc} \frac{c(a^2+b^2)}{a+b}\iff$$

$$(a+b+c)^2+2abc\left(\dfrac{1}{a+b}+\dfrac{1}{b+c}+\dfrac{1}{c+a}\right)\ge 4(ab+bc+ca)$$

$$a+b+c=p=1, \ ab+bc+ca=q \le \dfrac{1}{3}, \ abc =r$$

$$1+2r\ \dfrac{1+q}{q-r}\ge 4q \iff r\ge \dfrac{q(4q-1)}{1+6q}$$

$\dfrac{1}{4}\le q \le \dfrac{1}{3}:\ \ \ \  $ by   Shur $\ \ \ \ 1+9r\ge 4q$

$$\iff (4q-1)(1-3q)\ge0$$

Answer (score 1):

By Jensen :
$$a\left(\dfrac{b^3+c^3}{2} \right )^{1/3}+b\left(\dfrac{c^3+a^3}{2} \right )^{1/3}+c\left(\dfrac{a^3+b^3}{2} \right )^{1/3}\le (a+b+c)\left(\dfrac{a(b^3+c^3)+b(c^3+a^3)+c(a^3+b^3)}{2(a+b+c)}\right)^{1/3}\le a^2+b^2+c^2$$
$$\Leftrightarrow (a+b+c)^2(a(b^3+c^3)+b(c^3+a^3)+c(a^3+b^3))\le 2(a^2+b^2+c^2)^3$$

$$1.\ \ \  \  \ \  3(a^2+b^2+c^2)\ge (a+b+c)^2$$

$$2.\ \ \  \ \ \ 2(a^2+b^2+c^2)^2\ge 3(a(b^3+c^3)+b(c^3+a^3)+c(a^3+b^3))$$
$$a^4+b^4+4a^2b^2\ge 3(ab^3+ba^3)\Leftrightarrow (a-b)^2(a^2-ab+b^2)\ge 0$$
$$...$$

Comment: Can you use my lemma please

Answer (score 1):

$$a^2+b^2+c^2\ge\sum_{cyc} \frac{c(a^2+b^2)}{a+b}\iff$$
$$(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)(a^2+b^2+c^2)\ge\sum_{cycl}c(a^2+b^2)(b+c)(c+a)\iff$$
$$\sum_{cycl}(a^4b+b^4a+a^3b^2+b^3a^2+2ab^2c^2+2a^3bc)\ge\sum_{cycl}(2a^3b^2+2b^3a^2+2ab^2c^2+2a^3bc)\impliedby$$
$$a^4b+b^4a\ge a^3b^2+b^3a^2.$$